# How can I visualize / animate a 1D array in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation

I just finished writing a program in Python that simulates the kinetics of adsorption of gases onto a 1D lattice. The occupation lattice is just a numpy array that holds 20 integer values and an element of this array is equal to 0 if the lattice spot is empty or 1 if the lattice spot is occupied by a particle. The program runs over a for loop many times in which the program performs some calculations and then spits out the current occupation lattice at the end of each iteration. This is part of my research for school that I have to present on, and so my goal with writing this more simple program was to create an animation where I could visualize the code for my listeners. I would like to create something that looks like this:

[lattice representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km5fT.jpg)
(Can't post images, don't have enough reputation)

where, when a lattice spot is filled, I can fill the square red or put a little red circle inside of it. It would be great if the animation would just run in the python console, however if it exports to a file like matplotlib.animation does, that is fine as well! I'm really just looking for a program that I can accomplish this with, no need to give too much help on the code as long as it is manageable to figure out on my own!

The only animation package I've used before is matplotlib.animation, and I do not know how to create the representation of the lattice that I want with this package. If you know how I could do this within matplotlib.animation, that'd be great as I believe it'd be quite simple to draw the points within the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate it in console you can use ASCII art, [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) to color it and `time.sleep()`

Comment: Is ASCII art a package in python? I've never used that before

Comment: @spleen: No, it's not a Python package (nor is colorama for that matter), it's a a graphic design technique. See [ASCII art)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art).

Comment: @martineau thank you! I figured that out and animated it with ASCII art and colored 0's as the particles